# FDM versus fdtd for computational electromagnetics

Tags: electromagnetism, computational-physics

Every article I've seen on computational electromagnetics  uses the Yee fdtd algorithm, and I'm wondering if would be possible to do the same analyses using out of the box FDM with more data points, i.e. the Yee algorithm improves efficiency and that's its only benefit.

Comment: Might [Computational Science](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com) be better suited for this question?

Answer (score 1):

I did the 1st example in Schneider's online book both ways and got the same graphs, so I'm convinced the answer is that they are equivalent but that Yee's algorithm is faster by a factor of 4 (it uses 1/2 as many points and 1/2 as many time steps).